# Convert observable to promise and manipulate result

Tags: angular, observable

I want to calculate the total price for a set of items that are returned from my Firebase Database as an observable. However, the service returns nothing.

Here's what I tried:

**Service:**

```
  getRooms(): any {
    let result = {};
    this.items
      .toPromise()
      .then(items => {
        for (let item of items) {
          let name = item.name;
          let price = item.price;
          if (name in result) {
            result[name] += price;
          } else {
            result[name] = price;
          }
        }
      });
    return result;
  }
```

**Component**

```
export class InspirationComponent implements OnInit {

  rooms: any;

  constructor(private inspirationService: InspirationService) {
    this.items = this.inspirationService.getRooms();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for starters you shouldn't populate variable `this.items` like that. 
You should do like this:

**Component**

```
export class InspirationComponent implements OnInit {

  rooms: any;

  constructor(private inspirationService: InspirationService) {
    this.inspirationService.getRooms().then(result => {
         this.items = result ;
    });
  }
```

**Service**

```
 getRooms(): any {
    return this.http.get('url')
      .map(items => {
         let result = {}
         for (let item of items) {
          let name = item.name;
          let price = item.price;
          if (name in result) {
            result[name] += price;
          } else {
            result[name] = price;
          }
        }
         return = result ;
    }).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: *Why* it should be done like that? Manipulating data in component breaks the separation of concerns and produces WET code.

Comment: But there is no way to populate component's variable than from callback of REST call. The other way is to put variable to service and to populate it there.

Comment: This depends on how `this.items` is used. If it's bound in view, the original code probably should work (that's how $resource in A1 works). getRooms could just return a promise of modified result (currently it returns undefined). I don't see the reason why the entire `then` should be moved to component class.

Comment: @estus i agree, but if you return promise to this.items and in .then() return result, this.items will not have that data but promise. I modified answer influenced by your comment.

Comment: Yes, I believe it looks better. it should be `return this.http.get('url')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to resolve your promise. Change in the component.

```
export class InspirationComponent implements OnInit {

 rooms: any;

  constructor(private inspirationService: InspirationService) {
    this.items = this.inspirationService.getRooms((result) => {console.log(result);});
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```